# Run multiple commands inside a buildah container separated by the boolean AND (&&) operator from the command line

Tags: buildah

How can I run multiple commands *inside* a `buildah` container using bash's boolean AND `&&` operator from the host's command line?

Here's an example of my issue that starts from a `debian` image:

```
$ buildah pull debian:buster && container=$(buildah from debian:buster)
$ buildah run $container -- apt -y update && apt -y upgrade
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
bash: apt: command not found...
Install package 'apt' to provide command 'apt'? [N/y]
```

My host shell interprets the boolean AND `&&` outside the command for `buildah`. My expectation is to have the right side of the boolean AND to be run inside the `buildah` container.

Comment: untested: Try quoting the command you want to execute: `buildah run $container -- 'apt -y update && apt -y upgrade'`. *Some* programs interpret a command string as a singe shell command, but not all programs do that, it depends on how `buildah` was developed.

Comment: @user000001 I'm not very familiar with Go, but it seems like `buildah run` only allows a single command and its arguments: https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/ffef8a6c0b258c892299aef86405ec4d2377d0c5/cmd/buildah/run.go#L84

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about?

buildah run $container -- sh -c 'apt -y update && apt -y upgrade'.

Comment: This works, but why do we need to do that? Could you wrap the part after `--` with quotes and have the `buildah run` command accept the whole string?